# Web-run bug in visual studio2015

Tags: angularjs, caching, web, visual-studio-2015, runtime

I opened Web  a project in visual studio -my code is based on angular,html and css.

sometimes when I run the code on my Chrome  browser I cant see my recent changes of my code,and I see only the old code.

I think the problem is   the caching on my browser,but I don't sure about that.

Hope that someone has a answer to my problem...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few ideas:

1. When you refresh your page in Chrome, do a CTRL+F5 to do a full refresh.
2. Even if you set the expires to 0, it will still cache during the session. You'll have to close and re-open your browser again.
3. Make sure when you save the files on the server, the timestamps are getting updated. Chrome will first issue a HEAD command instead of a full GET to see if it needs to download the full file again, and the server uses the timestamp to see.

If you want to disable caching on your server, you can do something like:

```
Header set Expires "Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GM"
Header set Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
```

In .htaccess

4. OR disable Chrome cache:
   [image: Console Settings]
   [image: Disable Cache option]

When you reload the page, the `JS`, `CSS` should now get refreshed.